# PHP Session: How to Edit Other user's Session / Editting Session file

Tags: php, session

**EDIT - 2: See Sam's solution for the case. The old methods i'll still leave here as well as the problem itself, but a new solution was build based on Sam's solution, and it is available in the repository at github on the project i keep**

**EDIT - 1: SEE THE METHOD destroy(id) for a workaround**

Currently I have the need in some occasions in my System that requires other users session to be update with a new value. The current case now needs a single value to be changed in the session file of some users when a certain action is performed.
In my project i have created a class SessionHandlerCustom that implements the SessionHandlerInterface, and with that I have implemented a logic that creates a Custom session with an Id for each user. I can access the file in a custom directory, but strangely I can't use file_put_contents or file_get_contents to these Session files. I tried to work around with Session functions, and by using the read() function presented in the SessionHandlerCustom i was able to get all the contents from a user's session using it's SessionId.

The method working, **SessionFileGetValueByHashCode**, is the one that gets the content from a Session, and with some Key (usually the field name i want in the file), it will get the exactly string of that key with it's values.
The second method, not working at all, is the one that will actually change the value in the Session, but it just doesn't. I have tried manipulating the file directly with no success and have tried to use the SessionHandlerCustom->write() method but it has no effect.

Could anyone help me out and explain how is the correct way to change/manipulate the session of other user's ?

A System example: A common user is logged, while in the same time an administrator uses the Admin functions and change some value for this user. If the value is not something obtained from the database every time, the session variable for that current logged in user need to have its value changed.

**If you get curious, the System is Open Source, and you can access it here:**
https://github.com/msiqueira-dev/InfraTools

```
\*
This should be in the class that implements SessionHandlerInterface. This will actually delete the users session and force it to reload the whole session when it makes another request. The $SavePath variable is variable create and stored with the directory folder of the Session.
*/
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $file = $this->SavePath . "/sess_" . $id;
        if (file_exists($file)) 
            unlink($file);
        return true;
    }
```

**SessionFileGetValueByHashCode**

```
//The &$Value will be filled with the whole $Key and its values presented in the Session File. For example: SomeValue|s:0:"";
public function SessionFileGetValueByHashCode(&$Value, $Application, $SessionId, $Key)
{
        $Value = NULL;
        if(isset($Application) && !empty($Application) && isset($SessionId) && !empty($SessionId) && isset($Key) && !empty($Key))
        {
            $file = SESSION_PATH . $Application . "/sess_" . $SessionId;
            if(file_exists(($file)))
            {
                $str = $this->InstanceSessionHandlerCustom->read($SessionId);
                $start = strpos($str, $Key);
                $end=$start;
                while($str[$end] != '"')
                {
                    $Value .= $str[$end];
                    $end++;
                }
                $Value .= '"';
                $end++;
                while($str[$end] != '"')
                {
                    $Value .= $str[$end];
                    $end++;
                }
                $Value .= '"';
                if($Value != NULL)
                    return Config::RET_OK;
            }
        }
        return Config::RET_ERROR;
    }
```

**SessionFileUpdateValueByHashCode**

```
public function SessionFileUpdateValueByHashCode($Application, $SessionId, $OldValue, $NewValue)
    {
        if(isset($Application) && !empty($Application) && isset($SessionId) && !empty($SessionId) 
                               && isset($OldValue) && !empty($OldValue) && isset($NewValue) && !empty($NewValue))
        {
            $file = SESSION_PATH . $Application . "/sess_" . $SessionId;
            if(file_exists(($file)))
            {
                $str = $this->InstanceSessionHandlerCustom->read($SessionId);
                $str = str_replace($OldValue, $NewValue, $str, $count);
                if($count > 0)
                {
                    echo $str . "<br>";
                    if($this->InstanceSessionHandlerCustom->write($SessionId, $str))
                        return Config::RET_OK;
                }
            }
        }
        return Config::RET_ERROR;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ***can*** modify another users session (see below), although personally, I would recommend against it. As I imagine it can open up a whole world of session hijacking and other vulnerabilities.

With your example use case

> A common user is logged, while in the same time an administrator uses the Admin functions and change some value for this user. If the value is not something obtained from the database every time, the session variable for that current logged in user need to have its value changed.

You would be better of updating the value in the database and then just checking to see if it's changed before you process the next page. 
If you don't want to be checking multiple user fields before each page load then when you update the user in the admin panel, you can build a hash of the values and add it to a new column called session_hash. Then just compare this field on page load

But if you still want to modify another user's session, you can set your current `session_id` to the targets.

```
// End my current session and save its id
session_start();
$my_session_id = session_id();
session_write_close();

// Modify our target session 
session_id($target_id);
session_start();
$_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = false;
session_write_close();

// Start our old session again
session_id($my_session_id);
session_start();
```

**EDIT**

Example: https://www.samdjames.uk/session_example/index.php

Example Src: https://gist.github.com/SamJUK/c220e3742487567c6262238edf85695e

Comment: So, if you set a session_id, with a valid existing user id, i can them set a session_start and the current session will be the user of the id and not the one that called the script ? Is that right ? very interesting, i missed that! Thank you

Comment: Correct, but don't forget to reset your session id back afterward. Otherwise, you will continue using the other user's session in future scripts. I've added an poc example with the source in my answer above

Answer (score 0):

> Could anyone help me out and explain how is the correct way to
>   change/manipulate the session of other user's ?

The correct way is: **You don't**!

The session is designed to handle data of the current session, hence the name. If you interfere with the session of someone else, like in your example the admin user changing data for the user which has then immediately to be updated, you are almost certainly better off with a different method for this.

For example, you:

1. Could use a websocket to inform the users client about the change
2. Could use a token to validate against whether the data in the users session is still valid or not
3. Could use some persistency layer (e.g. database) to communicate the changes

There are certainly plenty more options, I recommend you re-think your architecture and come up with different ways than changing the session of a different user.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, there are, for now, just 2 cases, and both involves an administrator use, that would change the users session. I might indeed try the token to make the affected user create a new session, the only trouble I see on it, is that the user will have to log in again. If i keep going the path I was yesterday I might try using exec or deleting and recreating the file. Thank you for all the options you gave.

Comment: Just for a curiosity. Do you know why you can't edit the Session file directly ? Is the file fully locked ?