# PHP - Alternatives for storing values than session-cookies

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

### Recently I have opened a question here about a problem I was while modify session values for other user's session.

#### Link for the question: [PHP Session: How to Edit Other user's Session / Editting Session file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407889/php-session-how-to-edit-other-users-session-editting-session-file)

**Situation Description**:I was trying to directly edit the file stored in the server for each user. But due to protections and file lock, the best I could was to end the session when it needed any force update, by using a class that implements the SessionHandlerInterface.
Well, right now, i wish to know what other type of ways i could store values, rather than session-cookies or parameters on the URL (Database doesn't count). Is there a way to have it gathered in memory ?

**Example 1**: I user enter the System and changes the System language. I save the current language on the Session.

**Example 2**: A user enables the mobile version of the site by a implemented function, and it's stored in it's session that the site is mobile.

**Example 3**: A user is logged in, and it's object is stored in the session.

Comment: The most common way to store user settings is a database. You authenticate a user and create an account, then store the settings in a dedicated table. A session is a temporary state which can be expired.

Comment: I also use JS localstorage, but only for things like the state of a UI elements, such as what tab the user has open (jQuery-ui tabs) etc...  Just a few nice things I like to do for my clients.  They probably don't even appreciate it....

Comment: I will check out the JS LocalStorage, thank you. About the database strategy, well i am aware of this one, I just don't want to go over the database every time, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Saving temporary date in sessions is ok, just keep in mind it won't be there next time. Same goes with cookies, but with cookies you also have to consider the fact that user can alter them.

Loading data on login and storing it in session is not bad idea especially when you have to consider performance, there's really no reason to pull all data from database on every page load unless you just wanna kill MySQL server (once you have more data and concurrent users).

Comment: Sessions use cookies.... The session cookie tells the server which session data to use.  I am sure you know this, but it sounds like the Session is somehow different then a cookie `Same goes with cookies, but with cookies` - which it is, but it is related.  The difference is the session data is stored on the server (typically in a file) and then associated with the session ID which is stored in the session cookie.

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to point out cookies can be modified and possibly abused, it's much harder to alter session data.

Comment: So, you never store in session any sensitive information, agreed ?

Comment: Storing in sessions isn't that bad, storing in cookies is. User can literary edit or add any cookies they want. With sessions they can only hijack sessions if they can guess session ID, but they can't modify data in sessions unless they have access to filesystem on server.